# OpenMP crashes with parameter-defined array bounds

Tags: arrays, stack, fortran, openmp, bounds

I am having an issue with private arrays when using the `!$OMP TASK` construct.  Arrays listed as PRIVATE for tasks are crashing/becoming corrupted when their bounds are given by input parameters in the subroutine.  I am using static arrays to avoid the usual issues with allocatable arrays and `!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE`.

The following simplified code reproduces the issue, and crashes with SIGSEV:

```
SUBROUTINE do_work(n_in)
  USE omp_lib
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n_in
  INTEGER :: i, counter
  REAL, DIMENSION(n_in) :: a
  REAL, DIMENSION(20) :: b    

!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(a,i)
!$OMP SINGLE
    counter = 0
    DO WHILE(counter .LE. 20)
!$OMP TASK FIRSTPRIVATE(counter) PRIVATE(a,i)

     a(:) = 5.0
     DO i = 1,n_in
         a(1) = a(1) + a(i)
     END DO
     b(counter) = a(1)

!$OMP END TASK
     counter = counter + 1
    END DO
!$OMP END SINGLE
!$OMP END PARALLEL

END SUBROUTINE do_work
```

The issue, however, is cleared away simply by hardcoding the size of array `a` i.e. `REAL, DIMENSION(5) :: a`.  It is almost as if the task space is not aware of the array size parameter `n_in`.  However, I have verified `n_in` both inside and outside of the task construct and outside of the parallel construct.  Furthermore, if `a` is declared as a scalar, it works

Is the usage of `PRIVATE` clauses incorrect or incomplete?

SIDE NOTES:

1. I've written this simplified code to reproduce the problem.  In reality, I am parallelizing a series of linked lists, as you can probably tell from the structure
2. Any code calling this subroutine is serial.  There is no parallel nesting, recursion, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why, but in my case it works fine, if I include a radom print command (e.g print*,'test' or print*,a or even only print*, ) somewhere in the parallel region. If I comment it out, again I also get a SIGSEV ... strange. Sorry for this more or less answer.

Comment: That's very strange. Print statements do not affect the code on my machine. I've run into that behavior on other projects, and it has almost always been indicative of incorrect memory management somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, it is extremely strange, I never saw something similar before. But your problem seems strange anyhow. Maybe I should add that I used gfotran 4.8.2 . Of course the problme is related to bad memory managment, but I'm not familiar enough with openmp to make an educated guess.

Comment: Hey, I just tried it again with the PGI fortran compiler (version 14.3). There your example runs perfectly ... as it should. So I think this is a good reason to send your issue as a bug report to the gnu project.

Comment: I have encountered the same thing in some builds of the intel compilers as well.  
For now I'll leave this as a possible bug unless I can find more information.